# How to add an image in an email with swiftmailer?

Tags: symfony4, swiftmailer

I'm trying to have an image in the email.
I use Symfony 4 and SwiftMailer.
I read the documentation, the forum but it doesn't work.
 So I tried:

```
 $message = (new \Swift_Message('Title of the email'))
                        ->setFrom('myemailadress@xxxxxx.com')
                        ->setTo($data['email']);

                    $headers = $message->getHeaders();

                    $attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath('assets/img/logo.png');

                    $headers = $attachment->getHeaders();
 $message->setBody(
                        $this->renderView(
                            'resetemail.html.twig',
                            [ 'resetPassword' => $resetPassword], $headers
                        ),
                        'text/html'
                    );
$mailer->send($message);
                    return $this->redirectToRoute("requestMail");
```

For the Twig, I did:

```
<img id="customHeaderImage" align="top" label="Image" src="headers" alt="the title of the logo" class="w640" border="0" style="display: inline">
```

I also tried to replace the headers'part by:
$img = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('assets/img/logo.png'));

But I just have :
[image]

If you have a solution, I would love to read it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I found :

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Title of the email'))
                        ->setFrom('myemailadress@xxxxxx.com')
                        ->setTo($data['email'])
                        ->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath('build/logo.png')->setFilename('logo.png'));
```

So I attach the image to my message and I give it a name.

In my Twig I just put name in the src of the img.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('/assets/img/logo.png'))

Comment: I got the same result.